# Accessing Shared Entities through CRM 2011 SDK

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to return in code a list of particular entities that are **shared** with a team. In particular the shared views (userquery entity) objects that are being shared?

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up using:

```cs
RetrievePrincipalAccessRequest shareAccessRequest = new RetrievePrincipalAccessRequest
            {
                Principal = new EntityReference("team", myTeam.Id),
                Target = new EntityReference("userquery", uvEntity.Id)
            };

var shareAccess = (RetrievePrincipalAccessResponse)this.crmConnection.OrgServiceProxy.Execute(shareAccessRequest);
```

However the access rights that are returned are always **none** despite the view being shared with the team. I am not sure why?